# Spring Environment profiles and server properties

Tags: spring, spring-profiles

I have a requirement to load properties for different environments like DEV, QA and I have different properties file for each environment. So I solved this by setting environment property in server and accessing this value to load respective property files. When googled I found that Spring Environment Profiles provides the solution for similar scenarios. However, even here I have to set active-profile variable in server as environment variable.

What are the benefits of using Spring Environment Profiles over my native approach?

Comment: That you don't have to do your native approach. Saves you code and the best maintainable code is code not written. Next to that Springs Environment abstraction is more powerful as it can do a lot more then just property files it can also consult the system properties, environment properties, jodi, servlet context or what ever other `PropertySource` you can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Profile lets you override anything in the Spring Context, properties, beans etc, from environment to environment, customer to customer. It is a easy and clean way to have custom implementations at any level of your beans.

For example, Lets assume your are building a product which read data from a relational database, you can develop DAO layer with profile="default". Then if another customer of yours or you yourself want to provide NoSQL support, you can develop another DAO layer with profile="nosql". This will make sure you can same product on both support based on profile. Easy and clean.

I am working on a project which have profile="local" which will help you bring application locally with out any database dependency (kind of mock mode). You can think of million other applications like to make use of Profile concept.